# Discord Py - How to add multiple roles to all members on guild with text command

Tags: python, api, discord, roles

How can I add multiple roles to all users? What I have coded produces no errors, but it does not work. I am trying to loop through all members of the discord guild and then add the specified roles to each member.

```
    member = message.author
    cat1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767162794125557760)
    cat2 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767159884314574888)
    cat3 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767160508637642793)
    cat4 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767159426565013504)
    cat5 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767159149040500807)

    if message.content.startswith('!addroles'):
        if message.author.id == 80760379319259136:
            for person in message.guild.members:
                await person.add_roles(cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5)
            print("done.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine for me:

```
@client.command()
async def addroles(message):

    member = message.author
    cat1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767658943442583573)
    cat2 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767658997607170069)

    for person in message.guild.members:
        await person.remove_roles(cat1, cat2)
        print(person)
    print("done.")
```

Try to print out each person in the for loop. Maybe your if statments prove wrong cause you e.g. provided the wrong author id, and therefore the for loop doesn't get executed.

Also try to use commands instead of checking the message content:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def addroles(message):
    pass
```